# VS Code can't find definition file if path contains @ alias when using cmd+click

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, sass, alias, vite

I've set up a frontend stack with `vite` + `vue3` which works fine.
In here i'm using path aliases which also works well with both sass & js files.

Now I tried to set up VS Code to resolve alias paths to open the definition file when using *cmd+click*.
Unfortunately, VS Code could not find the clicked file (which leads me to the point that it's not able to resolve my aliases but vite is).

Around here i've found many solutions but none of them really worked for me.

My **File structure:**

```
/
├── src/
│   ├── sass/
│   │   ├── atomic-design
│   │        ├── molecules
│   │            ├── header.scss
│   │            └── hero.scss
│   └── style.scss
│   
├ jsconfig.js
├ vite.config.js
```

(*note:* i'did not list all files here unless the shown structure is the important part.)

My **vite.config.js**:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const path = resolve(__dirname);
const rootPath = resolve(__dirname, './src');

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  root: rootPath,
  plugins: [
    alias(),
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': resolve(path, './node_modules'),
      '@': resolve(path, './src'),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3001,
    hot: true,
  },
  build: {
    outDir: resolve(path, './dist'),
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(rootPath, 'index.html'),
        styleguide: resolve(rootPath, 'styleguide.html'),
        molecules: resolve(rootPath, 'molecules.html'),
      },
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: 'js/[name].js', // @link https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6552
        entryFileNames: 'js/[name].js',
        
        assetFileNames: ({name}) => {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ?? '')){
            return 'images/[name][extname]';
          }
          
          if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'css/style[extname]';
          }

          // if (/\.html$/.test(name ?? '')) {
          //   return '[name][extname]';
          // }

          if (/\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'fonts/[name][extname]';   
          }

          // default value
          // ref: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputassetfilenames
          return '[name][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  }
});
```

So i came up with the approach to add a **jsconfig.json** file to my root and set up the `paths` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "~/*": ["./node_modules/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

In **style.scss** i'm importing several sass files (see structure above).

Now if path contains an '@' alias, *cmd-click* to open definition file still fails.

Fails:
`@import '@/sass/atomic-design/molecules/heros';`

Works:
`@import '/src/sass/atomic-design/molecules/heros';`

So any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `@` modules in NPM means scoped package, so it's likely getting confused here.  eg.  `import "@types/node"`  The `@` here indicates a scoped package called `types`..  Also `"~/*": ["./node_modules/*"]` is not really great idea.  If these `node_modules` are you own, consider using a monorepo..